# Compile Multiple C Files on Mac?

Tags: c, gcc

I am new to C and using GCC. How do I compile multiple C files and then run them? I have multiple miles and each has different functions and they are supposed to run through the `main.c` file. My friend showed me through Windows but I am having issues figuring out how to do it on Mac.

What I was told:
Compile both files individually first:

```
gcc -Wall -c .\main.c
gcc -Wall -c .\file.c
```

Then compile both together into an executable:

```
gcc -o program file.o main.o
```

Then run executable with `.\program.exe`

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -o program ./main.c ./file.c` will build what you want in a single command. Beyond that, consider using a makefile or cmake (strongly advise the latter, btw).

Comment: The problem is the executable is not called `program.exe` on the mac, and the mac doesn't use backslashes as path separators. So the correct command is `./program` not `./program.exe`

Answer (score 2):

You should probably investigate makefiles, but this is quite easy. The following should do the trick.

```
gcc -o program file.c main.c
```

Feel free to add in whichever `-W` warning flags you want.

Note also that Macs do not use `\` as a directory separator but rather `/`, and executable files do not typically end in `.exe`.

Comment: I'm still having issues compiling. I did: 'gcc main.c mealExpenses.c miscExpenses.c travelTime.c vehicleExpenses.c -o Program' and 'gcc -o program main.c mealExpenses.c miscExpenses.c travelTime.c vehicleExpenses.c' but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try having `main.c` be the last file listed. The order does matter.